# Can you retrieve the Intuit User ID through OAuth

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am creating a connection to QuickBooks Online using the "Connect To QuickBooks" button as described on the following page:

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0010_Getting_Started/0020_Connect/0010_From_Within_Your_App/Implement_OAuth_in_Your_App

Using this method is it possible to retrieve the Intuit User ID that the user entered (when prompted during the Intuit Sign In dialog) so that I can associate that user ID with the access token, access token secret, and realmId that is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuit has a "current user" API which does what you're asking for. You could make this API request as soon as you get the OAuth tokens from Intuit, and then record the association in your app.

Here are the docs for it:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/0085_develop_quickbooks_apps/0004_authentication_and_authorization/platform_api

You basically do an OAuth GET request to this URL:

- https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/user/current

And Intuit returns a response like this which will give you the person's name and e-mail address:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<UserResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://platform.intuit.com/api/v1">
  <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
  <ServerTime>2012-04-13T18:47:34.5422493Z</ServerTime>
  <User>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
    <EmailAddress>JohnDoe@g88.net</EmailAddress>
    <IsVerified>true</IsVerified>
  </User>
</UserResponse>
```

Comment: the link provided does not work and when i use the get request url , i get an error saying [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)

Comment: @DeadDjangoDjoker   That is almost certainly an error on your end. Works fine for me. Post your code.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr.the link http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0060_Reference/Current_User_API could not be reach.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez  Link updated. Easy Google search to find the new one.

Comment: hi @KeithPalmerJr. Can you help me with this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213837/retrieve-users-company-information

Comment: When I am hitting https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/user/current url it showing me complete user information but while parsing xml it only return Errorcode 0 and ServerTime. Can you help me with this question ?

Comment: If you have a question, then you need to actually post a question on StackOverflow. Comments are not the appropriate place to ask questions unrelated to the original topic.