# Retrieve users/company information

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

On connecting to Quickbook within our app we are able to get access token and realmid but on trying to implement Get App Now we couldn't get any information after redirecting to our openid url. What I have tried so far is

```
define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY', $consumerkey);
        define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET', $consumersecret);

        define('OAUTH_URL', 'https://oauth.intuit.com/');
        define('APPCENTER_URL', 'https://appcenter.intuit.com/');

        define('OAUTH_REQUEST_URL', OAUTH_URL . 'oauth/v1/get_request_token');
        define('OAUTH_ACCESS_URL', OAUTH_URL . 'oauth/v1/get_access_token');
        define('OAUTH_AUTHORISE_URL', APPCENTER_URL . 'Connect/Begin');
        define('OAUTH_CURRENT_USER', APPCENTER_URL . 'api/v1/user/current');
try{

    $oauth = new OAuth(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY,OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET,OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
    $oauth->enableDebug();

    $request_token = $oauth->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CURRENT_USER,CALLBACK_URL);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    print_r($_GET);
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo $request_token;
    print_r($request_token);
    echo '</pre>';

} catch(OAuthException $e) {
    pr($e);
}
```

I can't get any valuable information on the above code, I maybe doing it wrong and expecting that there would be realmid and access token once the authorization is done and quickbooks redirect to our openid url. Any information would be appreciated.

Please note I really don't have knowledge about this as this is my first time using quickbooks api and related technologies.

**Updated**

```
<?php
    require 'openid.php';
try {
    # Change 'localhost' to your domain name.
    $openid = new LightOpenID($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);


    if(!$openid->mode) {
        if(isset($_GET['login'])) {

            $openid->identity = 'https://openid.intuit.com/OpenId/Provider';//'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
            $openid->required = array(
                'contact/email',
                'namePerson/first',
                'namePerson/last'
            );

            header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
        }
        ?>
        <form action="?login" method="post">
            <button>Login with Google</button>
        </form>
        <?php
    } elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
        echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
    } else {
        echo 'User ' . ($openid->validate() ? $openid->identity . ' has ' : 'has not ') . 'logged in.';
    }
} catch(ErrorException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

When the form above gets submitted it results into No OpenID Server found at https://openid.intuit.com/OpenId/Provider

Comment: The above code is about OAuth, yet your question is about OpenID. Please post your OpenID code, since your OAuth code is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. Im sorry if i posted that one, I really don't know what should I do. The only thing I know is we had set up openid url and i believe that the url will be triggered after clicking get app now and the user authorized our application.

Comment: OK, so what does the code look like for your OpenID URL? Please post it so that we can help you.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. as of the moment I only have those, nothing much. Im just checking what can I do to that url to get company information.

Comment: Please post what you've tried with OpenID so far. If you're not willing to provide any relevant code, we can't help you.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. I really don't have much on it. That's most of it. only require for the config that was not there and I really don't have much knowledge on this as this is my first time using quickbooks api and openid is also new to my. I think I will start searching about it.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. Do I need to use openid libraries for this?

Comment: Hi @KeithPalmerJr. Can you provide a simpel example to get the realmid through openid?

Comment: No, because you don't get the realm through OpenID. The realm comes from OAuth.

Comment: What can I get to openid?

Comment: OpenID is used to allow users to log in to your application using your Intuit credentials. You'll get an OpenID identifier, a name, and an email address for the user. OAuth is used to allow access to the QuickBooks/Payments APIs. You'll get a realm ID and OAuth credentials from OAuth.

Comment: Hi @KeithPalmerJr. would it be possible if you provide a simple example for getting users intuit email using openid?

Comment: Go grab this library: https://github.com/Dreyer/LightOpenID  There are examples included -- just substitute your and Intuit's URLs.  https://github.com/Dreyer/LightOpenID/blob/master/example-google.php  If you have trouble, please POST WHAT YOU'VE TRIED SO FAR.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. I have update the my post and I am having No OpenID Server found